# If statements in onclick and onselect not working in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, if-statement, onclick, onselect

This should be pretty straight forward, but I've been researching for over a day now and can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm making a web page in ASP.NET. What I'm trying to do is have a textbox with gray placeholder text that disappears and changes the font color to black when the textbox is clicked or selected. Here's my code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="addEditTextBox1" runat="server" onselect="if(style.color=='#999999'){style.color='Black'; this.value='';}" onclick="if(style.color=='#999999'){style.color='Black';this.value='';}" ForeColor="#999999" Width="250px">Revision #</asp:TextBox>
```

I've tried changing the "if" statement triggers to

```
if(style.color.value=='#999999'){...}
```

and

```
if(ForeColor=='#999999'){...}
```

and

```
if(ForeColor.value=='#999999'){...}
```

and many other syntaxes but I can't find one that works. I do know the onclick and onselect statements are working because if I replace the "==" with a "=" they trip 100% of the time, but that completely negates the whole idea of an "if" statement. I'm new to ASP.NET and JavaScript, so maybe there's something obvious I'm missing, but I can't find it anywhere. Here's some other information that I didn't think was relevant but may be helpful:

- Running in Visual Studio Professional 2012
- This is towards the top of the page's source code:

  ```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  ```
- Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.5.

Feel free to inquire if I left anything out. Thanks!

Comment: you should take your complex `onclick` events and turn them into javascript functions that are easier to debug.

Comment: you need to say `this.style.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either just simply use a HTML5 `placeholder` attribute, all the browsers support it now.

Or use this, works for both keyboard tabbing and mouse clicking:

`<asp:TextBox ID="addEditTextBox1" runat="server" onfocus="this.onfocus = null; this.value = ''; this.style.color = 'black';" ForeColor="#999999" Width="250px">Revision #</asp:TextBox>`

Btw, `onclick` is really just for buttons, you probably meant `onmousedown` and `onkeydown` - `onselect` is for when selecting text (to prevent it for example).

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I'm still not sure why the "if" statements didn't work, but this works exactly like what I was trying to do.

Comment: @ajlampman - they tripped just because of an error, but were not actualy triggering - see the last sentence in my answer